# Pyspark : How to compute number of of business days between two dates

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I want to compute the number of days between dates, ignoring weekends in pyspark.

I use this function but it doesn't work very well

```
nbe_of_days = F.dayofweek(F.datediff(F.current_date(), F.col("requirement_date_merged")))
```